# PayPal Direct Credit/Debit Card Payment available in Mexico?

Tags: paypal

I need to know if it is possible to accept direct credit card payments for a merchant based in Mexico.

In the REST API docs I found this list of country and currencies supported

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#direct-credit-card-payments

, which states that Mexican peso (MXN) is accepted, but it is not clear if the feature is available for mexican merchants.

Even if it were available, I found that there is a limit of direct payments (guest checkouts) that can be processed this way, unless Paypal Payments Pro is implemented, but Pro is ony available for USA, UK and Canada.

In that case, is there any way of implementing unlimited direct payments for merchants outside US/UK/Canada?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems a question out of scope

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just edited the question, is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately that reference location is really for currencies and direct credit card payments from a guest checkout point of view (credit card payment) to a paypal merchant account via guest checkout utilizing REST APIs.

I can see how this can be confusing when speaking of Direct Credit Card when that 'term' is mentioned a form of gateway transactions; Website Payments Pro and Payflow.  Hope that makes sense.